How do I relate objects in $SU(4)$ and $SO(6)$?
We know that $SU(4)$ is homomorphic $SO(6)$. I would like to understand how do we transform objects that we have, for example, in $SU(4)$, to objects in $SO(6)$.
For example, in $SO(6)$ we have scalars $X^I, I=1,...,6$. In $SU(4)$ we also have scalars $\phi^{[i,j]}$, $i,j=1,...4$.
In both cases $(6 = C_{4,2})$ we have the same number of scalares. So, how do i relate scalars in one group index to scalar in the other group? The question aroses because in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SUSY we have scalars (as well spinors and vectors) transformations that leaves the theory invariant. These transformations can also be written in $SO(6)$ index! But i don't know how to go from one to another.
I mean, in the same sense I can say $f = x^2+y^2+z^2$ in $R3$, and $f = r^2$ in $S_3$.

MSE has lots of this stuff: a, b, c,  ...

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193546/11127 and links therein.

I’m voting to close this question because it essentially belongs to [math.se].
